# Seeking a Library or API for Oscilloscope Data Measurement with Python, C, or C++ Integration

Tags: python, c++, c

I'm developing a simple oscilloscope using Python and Qt6.

For now I have completed the visual part (sine waves etc) and I was wondering if there is a library or API available for measuring oscilloscope data. I would prefer to use Python, but I'm open to bind code in C or C++ if necessary.

Thank you in advance !

P.S : I already have the data of "oscilloscope". For the moment I generate them by a script.